# Saving PDF with Save As in Adobe Reader causes Windows Installer to open and hang, also impacts other programs. Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-installer, adobe-reader, save-as

Dell XPS15 with standard Dell-installed Windows 10. Software is completely up to date, all drivers up to date.

When using the "Save As" open in Adobe Reader to either save a PDF to a new location / new name, or save a filled-in form, the Windows Installer opens with "Preparing to Install". This hangs and freezes the save-as process. As a result I'm unable to save any PDF forms.

This behaviour is relatively recent, within the last 3 months. I was prepared to ignore it as printing to a PDF printer remained an option and there does not appear to be an obvious, nor easily Google-able fix. However, the same problem occurs when saving a Mind Genius map file. It occurs the moment I attempt to "Save" any map. This too is new as I've generated numerous maps in the past.

This does not happen when saving Word or Excel files, even when exporting as PDFs. I'm not sure where I might find a log file that tells me what's going on. The installer popping up is already unexpected behaviour that I've not seen in the past when performing these actions.

Task Manager Image showing Reader and Installer
[image]

EDITED TO ADD: All hardware drivers, operating system updates and software releases are fully up to date. I have uninstalled and re-installed. I have tried turning it off and on again ;) . I have used the Acrobat Cleaner tool from Adobe, as well as Microsoft's Install repair tool. The typical basics have been covered.

Also - this is not specific to Reader. To date it has affected Adobe Reader, Mind Genius, Zoom and Ring Central. The first two programs are functional until attempting to save. The latter two are unable to install the local client and will not function.

Further edit:
[Task Manager Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeW2w.png)

Per @user1292580, added in the command line column. The unexpected result here is a blank entry. However, obviously related but unclear how, when left to sit on it's own long enough rather than kill it, a second popup shows Windows Installer, *Install server not responding*. I'm not sure if this is cause or effect.

On boot, the Windows Installer service is in manual start mode, and running. It remains running until I trigger the freeze by selecting "choose different folder" when "Save As" an existing PDF. The Process tab shows the little green leaf indicating the installer process has been blocked by Windows for performance reasons (not helpful here).
[Suspended Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYXmi.png)

If left long enough, the Windows Installer process will start, the Trusted Installer will show running in the Services tab and its PID will point to a Trusted Installer in Details, but the command line just gives us C:\WINDOWS\servicing\TrustedInstaller.exe

Left alone long enough (30-40 minutes), the system will respond with "Install server not responding" and a choice to retry or cancel. I updated the registry to generate a very complete log file, however no log file is generated (though a verbose log file was generated when installing a new displaylink driver, so I assume it works).

Comment: I would download the current Adobe Reader and repair your Adobe Reader installation  If you are getting a Windows installer for a specific program, that means the installation of that software, is incomplete.  Try that solution and [edit] your question.

Comment: Try reinstalling Adobe Reader. Uninstall Adobe, restart, then install the newest version of Adobe.

Comment: It's probably trying, and failing, to install an update. as others said, reinstalling it should fix it

Comment: On the details tab in Task Manager right click the column headers and choose *Command Line*. Post the command line of the Windows Installer process when it happens. Windows Installer supports *Advertised Features*  and *Install on First Use* (stupid features but they exist to save disk space).

Comment: That feature might be disabled in the free version of Adobe Reader, which is meant primarily for read-only use. You might also try any of the free alternative readers, such as PDF-XChange Viewer and Sumatra PDF.

Comment: @user1292580 thank you - that is the most helpful information to date, from any source.

Comment: Post the command line here. To understand (or try to) the command line type `msiexec /?` for help on Windows Installer's command line. `msiexec` is the exe file for Windows Installer.

Comment: @user1292580 Command line was empty for the installer row per the image in the edited question.

Comment: Can you please use the *Details* tab in Task Manager. The *Processes* tab tries to show useful, but inaccurate information, so it is useful to ordinary people. The *Processes* tab does a lot of guessing whereas the *Details* tab shows what is.

Comment: If it is blank then try this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d.  Windows Installer also has a logging mode but one needs to know the command line.

Comment: MSIExec talks to the Windows Installer service. Make sure it is not disabled in Services (Right click This PC, Manage, Services and Applications). Then right click it and choose Properties - Dependencies' tab and make sure the other service it relies on is ok.

Comment: @user1292580 Windows Installer is not disabled, start up method is manual (and can't be changed). When the Processes tab shows Windows Installer, there is no Windows Installer or Trusted Installer in the Details tab, and Trusted Installed in the Services tab shows it as Stopped. If left alone long enough, the service will start with a PID that takes you to the Trusted Installed details, but there's nothing in the command line besides pointing to itself. The Processes tab never spits out a PID to chase down. RPC is all running in automatic mode.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!**

As part of the on-going troubleshooting of this specific problem, I was re-installing Norton AV (many programs have been uninstalled/re-installed during this process), but was also watching the system Event Viewer. During the install process, a Windows Installer pop-up appeared but then nothing happened. I was able to connect that to an entry in the log stating

> Detection of product '{44C80B40-F98A-4CFF-84AC-7984F6F8411C}', feature 'Shared', component '{F6985392-6908-483D-8325-589F98CCDB32}' failed.  The resource 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SOLIDWORKS Shared\SwHelpViewer\lang\English\swerrpage.htm' does not exist.

[Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJx7M.png)

I do use SolidWorks but was not using it at the time. It seemed entirely unconnected to the activity that was taking place. A google search ended up at a SW user forum discussing issues with SolidWorks' help function, that often brings up a "no internet connection" error even when connected. The proposed solution was to delete the local html page, which solved the help problem. However buried at the bottom of the thread was a post that outlined the same issue I'd been having here - freezing on *Save-As* operations with an Installer pop-up.

A check of the file directory showed that at some point in the past I had indeed deleted the html page in a successful attempt to fix the help issue. A co-worker sent a copy of his *swerpage.htm* file, I dropped it into its folder, rebooted the machine and the problem is now solved.

I can't believe how bizarre this issue turned out to be. Short of uninstalling SW, I would never have discovered the connection without that post.

Thanks to @user1292580 for trying valiantly to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Re-install your adobe reader and if you have any updates pending to your windows have them installed.